# jQuery / FancyBox: Display tips and tricks first, if not cookie set?

Tags: jquery, cookies, fancybox

I have created an image gallery in which a user clicks a thumbnail and a FancyBox box pops up.

The image within the popup has a rollover showing before retouching and after retouching.

I want to set up FancyBox to show a caption (or similar) when an image is clicked for the first time, to explain that users can rollover to see the before and after.

How would I go about doing this?

Many thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery Cookies plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) to test and set cookies:

```
if (!$.cookie("rollover")) { 
  $("#caption").show();
  $.cookie("rollover", "dont show again");
}
```

`$.cookie("rollover")` will return null if the cookie hasn't been set.